# Can I place Function definition in one script and function call in another script

Tags: shell

Can I place Function definition in one script
and function call in another script in shell?

Comment: (No call without having seen (*source*) the definition, far as I remember.) (This not being a "core" programming question, you may have better luck in a different forum, e.g. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: You will have to `source` the definition script into the call script. From a bash prompt, enter `help .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here's an example:

```
$ cat library.sh
function func() {
  echo "hello"
}

$ cat main.sh
source library.sh
func

$ ./main.sh
```

Comment: It works well. Thanks @Tomas. Your reply is very helpful.

Comment: Hi @Preet100, I'm glad the solution works for you :-). Could you then please "accept" the answer (that'll give me some points, that will eventually enable me to comment on other answers). Thanks, *t

Comment: Thanks @Preet100 :-)!